# How to connect to MQTT broker with authorization with MQTT Spark streaming library

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ibm-cloud, spark-streaming, mqtt

I'm trying to connect broker with authorization( BlueMix IoT Foundation), but don't know how to provide credentials? How do I do it with Spark?

Comment: Could you say how you are trying to connect? Posting your code is never a bad idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to connect to brokers with authorization using default MQTT connector from `SparkStreaming`. You have to redefine [MQTTInputDstream](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/7478c8b66d6a2b1179f20c38b49e27e37b0caec3/external/mqtt/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/mqtt/MQTTInputDStream.scala) in your own way to enable authentication.

Answer (score 2):

I have customized the spark-streaming-mqtt-connector library from Apache Spark and added the following,

- Added TLS v1.2 security such that the communication is always secured.
- Stored topic along with the payload in the RDD.

The library is available here - https://github.com/sathipal/spark-streaming-mqtt-with-security_2.10-1.3.0. Also, added more detail in how to use the library to connect to IBM Watson IoT Platform. Let me know if you have any queries.